# Ngx-bootstrap modal: how to pass data to the modal component.ts instead of to the html template?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-modal

I'm able to collect the data passed in the `initialState` object, for example in this fragment of code:

```
   const initialState = {
        titulo: titulo,
        origen: origen,
        th1: "Número",
        th2: "Nombres",
        modalFor: "Locales"
      };
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent, {
        initialState,
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
      });
```

and interpolate its properties in the ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent.html.

But if I wanted the values passed to the modal in `const initialState` to be, let's say, get printed in the console in the `ngOnInit()` method of ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent.ts ¿How can I achieve that? It is not recognized in the .ts file of the modal.

Thanks.

this is the code of the component that launches the modal:

```
 openModal(origen, titulo) {
    this.origen = origen;

    if (origen === "cliente") {
      const initialState = {
        titulo: titulo,
        origen: origen,
        th1: "RUT",
        th2: "Nombres",
        modalFor: "Clientes",
        rutClientes: this.requestTres.rutCliente,
        rutOperador: this.requestTres.rutOperador
      };
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent, {
        initialState,
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
      });
    } 
    else if (origen === "local") {
      if (!this.forma.controls.rutCliente.value) {
        swal("Seleccione un cliente", "", "warning");
      } else {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length / crecion del request para locales

        this.documentosService.localRequest.rutCliente = this.requestTres.rutCliente = parseInt(
          this.forma.controls.rutCliente.value.toString().slice(0, -1),
          10
        );
        this.documentosService.localRequest.rutOperador = this.rutOperador;

        let initialState = {
          titulo: titulo,
          origen: origen,
          th1: "Número",
          th2: "Nombres",
          modalFor: "Locales",
          rutClientes: this.requestTres.rutCliente,
          rutOperador: this.requestTres.rutOperador
        };

        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent, {
          initialState,
          backdrop: "static",
          keyboard: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the .ts of the modal:

```
import { DocumentosService } from './../../../core/consultaService/documentos.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ConsultasService } from '../../../core/consultaService/consultas.service';

import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
  FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';
import { ClientesService } from '../../../core/consultaService/clientes.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cliente-o-local-pop-up',
  templateUrl: './clienteOlocalPopUp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clienteOlocalPopUp.component.scss']
})
export class ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent implements OnInit {

  origen: string;
  titulo: string;
  forma: FormGroup;
  forma2: FormGroup;
  clientes: any;
  clientesData: any;
  cliente: any;
  cargando = false;


  constructor(
    public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private clientesService: ClientesService,
    private consultasService: ConsultasService,
    private documentosService: DocumentosService
  ) {
    this.forma2 = new FormGroup({
      nombreCliente: new FormControl(),
      modalFor: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.initialState); // initiaState is highlighted as if does not exist.

  }
}
```

`initialState`is highlighted as if does not exist despite it was passed in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that the `initialState` object that you pass in  `this.modalService.show` is not passed in as a property to your component it only contains the properties of your component that are gonna be updated, it doesn't initialize an `initialState` property

if you show the modal like

```
const initialState = {
        titulo: titulo,
        origen: origen,
        th1: "Número",
        th2: "Nombres",
        modalFor: "Locales"
      };
      this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent , {
        initialState,
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false
      });
```

then the properties that are initialized in yor modal component are `titulo`, `origen`, `th1`, `th2` and `modalFor`. If you want an `initialState` property initialized in that component then you must do something like

```
const initialState = {
            titulo: titulo,
            origen: origen,
            th1: "Número",
            th2: "Nombres",
            modalFor: "Locales"
          };
          this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent , {
            initialState : {initialState},
            backdrop: "static",
            keyboard: false
          });
```

That's why when you say `console.log(this.initialState);` it gives undefined, it should be `console.log(this.titulo);` or any other property that you decide

Comment: I get `undefined` by doing: `ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.origen);
  }`
That's exactly my question. How not to get undefined

Comment: That shouldn't happen, I've used ngx-bootstrap modal several times in my projects and I've been able to receive initialState in my components, maybe the issue is inside ClienteOlocalPopUpComponent can you provide the code for it?

Comment: Yes, I'll provide the code :) Please, have a look at it.

Comment: I see your problem now so I updated my answer above